# Assignment of values of multiple columns in a list using conditions doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign values of 2 columns of some rows with other 2 columns of the same rows.
The code as of now looks like that:

```
to_fill = ['a','b'] 
fill_with = ['x', 'y'] 
temp_test_df.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),to_fill] = temp_test_df.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),fill_with]
```

That piece returns NA in the to fill columns (a and b).

However when I break it down to 2 separate statements with 1 column name in each, it works properly.

```
temp_test_df.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),'a'] = temp_test_df[.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),'x']]

temp_test_df.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),'b'] = temp_test_df[.loc[(temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021),'y']]
```

What am I doing wrong in the first block, and what can I do better if I want to perform the same with many more columns? just write it in the second way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert second DataFrame for numpy array, because columns alignment:

```
temp_test_df =   pd.DataFrame({'week' : (1, 20, 30),
                               'year' : (2021, 5, 2021),
                               'a' : (4, 5, 6),
                               'b' : (0, 1, 2),
                               'x' : (7, 8, 9),
                               'y' : (5, 6, 7)})

to_fill = ['a','b'] 
fill_with = ['x', 'y'] 
mask = (temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021)
temp_test_df.loc[mask,to_fill] = temp_test_df.loc[mask, fill_with].to_numpy()
```

Or use `rename` for same columns names:

```
to_fill = ['a','b'] 
fill_with = ['x', 'y'] 

d = dict(zip(fill_with, to_fill))

mask = (temp_test_df['week'] < 13) & (temp_test_df['year'] == 2021)
temp_test_df.loc[mask,to_fill] = temp_test_df.loc[mask, fill_with].rename(columns=d)
print (temp_test_df)
   week  year  a  b  x  y
0     1  2021  7  5  7  5
1    20     5  5  1  8  6
2    30  2021  6  2  9  7
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I understand why the second option deals with it correctly. 
@jezrael

Comment: @HermanK - because after rename get columns `renamed` from `fill_with` to `to_fill`, so is matched `a, b` to `a, b` (second is renamed x, y to a, b)